# How to I align href link(buttons) to the middle of the webpage as they are acting as buttons in the center of page? Note : It should be responsive

Tags: css

```
<div class="btn_main">
    <a href="#">link1</a>
    <a href="#">link2</a>
</div>
```

I want to make them in the middle of the page with responsiveness

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fully Responsive with the Center.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Button Center</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    *{
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    body{
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    .btn_main{
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="btn_main">
      <a href="#">link1</a>
      <a href="#">link2</a>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```